# How can i copy a file in smali

Tags: android, copy, smali

I'm reverse engineering an app.
I want to copy an image from res/drawable to internal storage in smali
The java code is
`FileUtil.copyFile("android.resource://com.package.name/drawable/app_icon.png", "/storage/emulated/0/App_name/icon/");`

**I just want this code in smali language**

*I want to convert it into smali.*

Comment: If you only want Smali code, the `[java]` tag is irrelevant.  Removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easy option to generate Smali code from Java code:

Just use AndroidStudio, create a new App project, and paste the Java code you want to have in the `onCreate` method of the main Activity (or add a custom method).

Then build the APK and decompile it using [Apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) or [Jadx](https://github.com/skylot/jadx) (Jadx can display for each class also the Smali code) to get the Smali code. Just copy the relevant parts out of the shown smali code.